# How do I check what IPs are being blocked by my security group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to find out the IP that is getting blocked so that I can give it access. Is there a Log I can see of the security group to know which IPs have tried to access my RDS but were unable to?

Comment: Ask the owner of the client that's trying to connect to provide you with their IP address?

Answer (score 2):

Security Groups themselves don't have logs. The only place that rejection will be displayed is in the [VPC Flow Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html), but you would have to enable VPC Flow Logs first.

Note that if this traffic is coming from another resource inside the VPC, you should be enabling traffic by Security Group ID instead of specific IP addresses.